# PHP: Not equal to not taking effect

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, advanced-custom-fields

I am having issues with a simple not equal to operator that's not taking effect for some reason.

Made a field backend which returns a specific user ID whilte get_current_user_id(); also returns user ID. I have tried echo bot $user and $current where they both returns user ID 9 as expected on my test user.

Since they $current and $user is returning same user ID the content should not be shown but for some reason it does. I am using != as a PHP operator for "Not equal to" - What am I missing ?? See code below:

```
$user = get_field("user");
$current = get_current_user_id();

if( in_array( "bestyrelsevalg", $row['bestyrelse'] ) && $user != $current )
```

Comment: Wrong brackets, your `&&` part is inside the `in_array`. Change to `if( in_array( "bestyrelsevalg", $row['bestyrelse']) && $user != $current )`

Comment: wooops... I've changed it but no luck :(

Comment: 2nd argument of in_array function should be an array. Is the variable $row['bestyrelse'] an array?

Comment: yes... The array part works as expected. Been using the code for years but is now trying to implement the "is not equal" operator in order to exclude users from viewing the content. But no luck so far.

Comment: You can also check if $user and $current are of the same type . If one is string and the other number it wont work. e.x $user='1' and $current=1 . So before comparing them, convert them to the same type (possibly integer)

Comment: can you show us the output of `var_dump($user)` and `var_dump($current)`?

Comment: Thats not right @gijoe, it is not necessary previous casting before comparing var of distinct types. In php "9" == 9 return true (and "9" != 9 is false). On the other hand using the `===` operator would return false on "9" === 9. See the tables of comparison here: https://www.php.net/types.comparisons

Comment: @francisconeto is right, we need to see what your conditions are actually comparing, So paste in a var_dump of the two variables - One error here, could f.x be, that your ACF field is set to return the object instead of the ID

Comment: hmm... I am trying to var_dump but nothing is showing: $content = var_dump($current); return $content; - if i use print_r instead of var_dump it just returns 1.

Comment: Got it to work by using ob_get_clean .... They both returns int(9)

Comment: if I switch user and var_dump($current) it returns int(5) while var_dump($user) still returns int(9) which is as expected. Just checking to make sure I wasn't cached or something :)

Comment: what about `var_dump(in_array( "bestyrelsevalg", $row['bestyrelse'] ));`?